# ¿Como llamar más de un objeto en treeview de tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy tratando de llamar todos los objetos de una lista de un webservice que estoy consumiendo, cuando hago print del append funciona como debe, pero en tkinter, especificamente en el treeview solo me muestra un objeto de esa lista, como puedo hacer que me muestre todos como lo hace en el print append? si quiero un item específico, en este caso _moneda por ejemplo?

```
    from suds.client import Client
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

from suds.client import Client

url ='https://www.banguat.gob.gt/variables/ws/TipoCambio.asmx?WSDL'

cliente = Client(url)

resultados = cliente.service.TipoCambioRango("23/02/2021", "23/02/2022" )

lista = []
for item in resultados['Vars']['Var']:
    _moneda = item['moneda']
    _fecha = item['fecha']
    _venta = item['venta']
    _compra = item ['compra']
    _lineas = str(_moneda) +','+ _fecha+','+str(_venta)+','+str(_compra)
    lista.append(_lineas)
    print(lista)

win = Tk()

my_tree = ttk.Treeview()

my_tree['columns'] = ("Moneda", "Fecha", "Venta", "Compra")
my_tree.column("#0", width="0", minwidth="0")
my_tree.column("Moneda", anchor=W, width=120)
my_tree.column("Fecha", anchor=CENTER, width=80)
my_tree.column("Venta", anchor=W, width=120)
my_tree.column("Compra", anchor=CENTER, width= 80)

my_tree.heading("#0", text="", anchor=W)
my_tree.heading("Moneda", text="Moneda", anchor=W)
my_tree.heading("Fecha", text="Fecha", anchor=CENTER)
my_tree.heading("Venta", text="Venta", anchor=W)
my_tree.heading("Compra", text="Compra", anchor=CENTER)

my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=0, text="", values=(_moneda , _fecha, _venta, _compra))

my_tree.pack(pady=20)


win.title("Proyecto Progra 3")
win.geometry("659x500")
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Usa un bucle for que recorra la lista e insertas uno a uno el contenido de la lista.